# Google Drive form answers are not dates in the spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

I created a simple form with in Google Drive. The User choose a Date and a checkbox. In further calculations I have to compare the "date". But in the answers it isn´t shown as a date. I can set the format of the column to date and everything is fine, but all the new answers dont have a format.

The formated dates are aligned left in the sheat and all the new unformated dates a right aligned.

Is there any script wich converts new dates to the right format? Or any other suggestions?

cheers

Comment: I got an workaround to convert those numbers to dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an auxiliary column. There I enter the following formula in the second row. This is filled in automatically for all following lines.
The date is on the "C" column.

```
=ArrayFormula( IFERROR( if(C2:C<>0;(TEXT(day(C2:C);"00")&"."&text(month(C2:C);"00")&"."&YEAR(C2));"")))
```